# looping through one list while sampling another

Tags: r, for-loop, tidyverse

I'm trying to simulate the process of birds pairing with one another. I simulated a population of males and females ('agents_for_pairing'), and the way the process should work is:

1) If the day of the breeding season ('day') is equal to the date a male is available (aDate), then the male is available to breed on that day or any day after.

2) If a female is also available (aDate = day[i]) then it randomly selects an available male (hasn't paired yet and also available). If there are multiple females and males available, the code should loop through each female and pair it with a male on that particular day.

3) If a female is ready to breed but no males are available, then its available date increases by one (aDate + 1) and it tries again the next day (and the process repeats until it pairs).

4) Once individuals are paired, they take on the id of their mate and their status changes (paired == TRUE).

I split the population into females and males, then I loop through each day of the breeding season, and each available female (if there are any). My code looks like this:

```
library(tidyverse)

'%ni%' <- Negate('%in%')

agents_for_pairing <- tribble(
  ~id, ~mateID, ~sex, ~paired, ~aDate,
  34, NA, 'F', FALSE, 86,
  56, NA, 'F', FALSE, 90,
  14, NA, 'F', FALSE, 90,
  113, NA, 'M', FALSE, 86,
  2, NA, 'M', FALSE, 89,
  23, NA, 'M', FALSE, 87
)  
agents_for_pairing

# split into list by sex
agents_for_pairing <- agents_for_pairing %>%
  mutate(mateID = as.numeric(mateID)) %>%
  split(.$sex)
agents_for_pairing

day <- seq(86, 90, by=1) # days to loop through

for (i in seq_along(day)) { # for each day

  print(day[i])

    if (nrow(agents_for_pairing$F %>% filter(aDate == day[i] & paired == FALSE)) < 1) { # if there are no females available

      print('no females available') # do nothing but print this message

    } else {

      for (j in 1:nrow(agents_for_pairing$F %>% filter(aDate == day[i] & paired == FALSE))) { # go through female that is ready to breed

        if (nrow(agents_for_pairing$M %>% filter(id %ni% (agents_for_pairing$F$mateID) & aDate <= day[i] & paired == FALSE)) > 0) { # find a male that hasn't been taken yet & available

        mate <- sample_n(agents_for_pairing$M %>% filter(id %ni% (agents_for_pairing$F$mateID) & aDate <= day[i] & paired == FALSE), size=1, replace=FALSE) # randomly sample one mate

        agents_for_pairing$F[j,]$mateID <- mate[[1]] # make it your mate
        agents_for_pairing$F[j,]$paired <- TRUE # change status to paired now

        agents_for_pairing$M <- agents_for_pairing$M %>% # make sure paired male has same status and adopts female id
          mutate(
            mateID = case_when(
              id == mate$id ~ agents_for_pairing$F[j,]$id,
              TRUE ~ mateID
            ),
            paired = case_when( 
              mateID > 0 ~ TRUE, # males without a mate remain unpaired
              TRUE ~ FALSE
              )
            )

      } else {

        agents_for_pairing$F[j,]$paired <- FALSE # if no males available, remain unpaired
        agents_for_pairing$F <- agents_for_pairing$F %>%
            mutate(
              aDate = case_when(
                aDate == day[i] & paired == FALSE ~ aDate + 1, # and increase date available by a day
                TRUE ~ aDate
                )
              )
      }
    }
  }
}

agents_for_pairing
```

Somewhere there appears to be an error in the code...not all females are able to pair, even though there are enough males:

```
$F
# A tibble: 3 x 5
     id mateID sex   paired aDate
  <dbl>  <dbl> <chr> <lgl>  <dbl>
1    34     23 F     TRUE      86
2    56      2 F     TRUE      90
3    14     NA F     FALSE     90

$M
# A tibble: 3 x 5
     id mateID sex   paired aDate
  <dbl>  <dbl> <chr> <lgl>  <dbl>
1   113     34 M     TRUE      86
2     2     56 M     TRUE      89
3    23     34 M     TRUE      87
```

This is a more complicated for-loop than I've attempted in the past, and I'm wondering if there's an indexing issue? I think in the 2nd for-loop where I try to pair each available female I may be assigning its mate incorrectly...any advice? Should look something like this:

```
$F
# A tibble: 3 x 5
id mateID sex   paired aDate
<dbl>  <dbl> <chr> <lgl>  <dbl>
1    34     113 F     TRUE      86
2    56      2 F     TRUE      90
3    14     23 F     FALSE     90

$M
# A tibble: 3 x 5
id mateID sex   paired aDate
<dbl>  <dbl> <chr> <lgl>  <dbl>
1   113     34 M     TRUE      86
2     2     56 M     TRUE      89
3    23     14 M     TRUE      87
```

Comment: can you post the expected output table?

Comment: I added the expected output @YOLO
Should look different every time, but basically all birds should pair in this example and aDate should not change

Answer (score 1):

This was an interesting problem to work on. I never did figure out what was wrong with your code, but here is mine.

```
library(tidyverse)
```

I label your `agents for pairing` as `state`:

```
state1 <- tribble(
  ~id, ~sex, ~aDate, ~mateID,
  34, 'F', 86, NA,
  56, 'F', 90, NA,
  14, 'F', 90, NA,
  113, 'M', 86, NA,
  2, 'M', 89, NA,
  23, 'M', 87, NA
)

minday <- min(state1$aDate)
maxday <- max(state1$aDate)

days <- seq(minday, maxday, 1)
```

Define a `stateframe` object that will hold all of the evolutions:

```
stateframe <- rep(NA, length(days)) %>% as.list()
```

Names the states by the "day":

```
names(stateframe) <- c(minday:maxday)
```

The first stateframe is the initial `df` you gave:

```
stateframe[[1]] <- state1
```

Helper function `whichAvailable`. Output is a list of `id`s that are available given a state and sex:

```
whichAvailable <- function(date, mysex){ # date is in seq_along(days), sex as character M / F
return(
  stateframe[[date]] %>%
  mutate(available = ifelse(aDate <= as.numeric(names(stateframe[date])) &
                              is.na(mateID), TRUE, FALSE)) %>%
  filter(sex == mysex, available == TRUE) %>%
    select(id) %>%
    unlist() %>%
    as.numeric()
  )
}
```

Outer sequence loops through the days, inner sequence loops through the same data frame until no more pairings can be found.

```
for (i in seq_along(days)) {
  availablePairings <- c(length(whichAvailable(i, "F")), length(whichAvailable(i, "M")))
  # loop through day `i` until no more pairings can be found
  if (all(availablePairings > 0)) {
    # mate all available males and females
    for (j in 1:max(availablePairings)) {
      maleid <- whichAvailable(i,"M")[[1]] # pick the first male in the list
      femaleid <- whichAvailable(i, "F")[[1]] # pick the first female in the list
      stateframe[[i]][stateframe[[i]]$id == maleid,]$mateID <- femaleid
      stateframe[[i]][stateframe[[i]]$id == femaleid,]$mateID <- maleid
    }
  } 
  stateframe[[i + 1]] <- stateframe[[i]]
}
```

Result:

```
> stateframe[[5]]
# A tibble: 6 x 4
     id sex   aDate mateID
  <dbl> <chr> <dbl>  <dbl>
1    34 F        86    113
2    56 F        90      2
3    14 F        90     23
4   113 M        86     34
5     2 M        89     56
6    23 M        87     14
```